# How to repeatedly swap elements in scala list?

Tags: scala

I have a List

```
val a= List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

I want to consecutive swap the elements How can I do this?

Expected ans is

```
List(2,1,4,3,6,5,7)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).grouped(2).flatMap(_.reverse).toList
res10: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7)
```

Answer (score 6):

The key is to use grouped while working on groups:

```
val a= List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
a.grouped(2).flatMap{_.reverse}.toList
//res0: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7)
```

Answer (score 5):

Sliding can also be used :

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).sliding(2,2).foldLeft(List[Int]()){(r,c) => r :+ c.last :+ c.head }.toList
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5)
```

Or

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).sliding(2,2).flatMap(_.reverse).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function for repeated swaps, as follows,

```
def f(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: Nil => List(x)
    case x :: y :: ys => y :: x :: f(ys)
  }
}
```

Note that

```
f(a)
List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7)

f(f(a)) == a
true
```